# Mysql- Not allowing duplicate entries to be inserted

Tags: mysql

I have the following Stored procedure with me which allows to insert into the Database.I want to change the the stored procedure such that duplicate entries should not be entered.The columns that I want to use for checking the duplicate are  Material_Name and Material_Data.how should i change the SP? Someone help me.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_upload_file`(IN Training_Id INT,IN filename VARCHAR(200), IN path VARCHAR(200),IN materialdata MEDIUMBLOB)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `training_material`
    (`Training_Id`,
    `Material_Name`,
    `Material_Path`,
    `Material_Data`,
    `Created_Date`,
    `Modified_Date`)
 VALUES 
    (Training_Id,
    filename,
    path,
    materialdata,
    NOW()
    ,NOW());

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Create a unique index on those columns.

Comment: and if you need to ignore errors change `INSERT INTO` to `INSERT IGNORE INTO`

Answer (score 2):

alter the table by creating `UNIQUE` *constraint*,

```
ALTER TABLE training_material
ADD CONSTRAINT trainmat_UQ UNIQUE(Material_Name, Material_Data)
```